# Pandas: Create New Dataframe from Certain Columns in Other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe, `old`, like this:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
```

I want to make a new dataframe, `new`, that copies `col2` from `old` and fills in `-1` as dummy values for its other columns:

```
  col2 new_col1 new_col3
0   2   -1       -1
1   3   -1       -1
2   4   -1       -1
```

I suppose I could do iterate row by row and fill in `-1` for any column not in `old` but figure there must be a better, likely vectorized way.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do `reindex` .

```
df.reindex(columns=['col2','newcol1','newcol3'],fill_value=-1)
Out[183]: 
   col2  newcol1  newcol3
0     2       -1       -1
1     3       -1       -1
2     4       -1       -1
```

Comment: Where do you specify the value for columns that aren't in `old`?

Answer (score 2):

#### `assign`

```
df[['col2']].assign(new_col1=-1, new_col3=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
new = old.copy()
new[['col1','col3']] = -1

>>> new
   col1  col2  col3
0    -1     2    -1
1    -1     3    -1
2    -1     4    -1
```

Or more generally, to change all columns besides `col2` to `-1`:

```
new = old.copy()
new[list(set(new.columns) - {'col2'})] = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
new=pd.DataFrame({'col2':old['col2'],'new_col2':-1,'new_col3':-1})
print(new)
```

Output:

```
   col2  new_col2  new_col3
0     2        -1        -1
1     3        -1        -1
2     4        -1        -1
```

@sacul Thanks for telling me

Comment: No need to do `[-1]*3`: `new=pd.DataFrame({'col2':old['col2'],'new_col2':-1,'new_col3':-1})`